# Extract text after "/" in a data frame column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that has two columns `Link` and `Value`. The `Link` column has values like "abcd.com/efgh/ijkl/mnop" and is a URL. There are 10,000 rows in this frame which i have taken from a sample of 100,000 rows.

Now I want to extract the data after the last "/" from left to right or first "/" from right to left. So for eg in the above sample shown I was to extract "mnop"

I want to do this for all the 10,000 rows that is there in the column `Link` while the `Value` column should not be effected.

I was able to to use

```
a = sapply(webdatatest, substring, 36)
```

but this is not a dynamic method as positions of last "/" would change. Also this was effecting the second column also.

So need some help on this.

Comment: I didn't get you. From the "abcd.com/efgh/ijkl/mnop" in need "mnop".And want to repeat this for all the rows.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try `basename()`.  It

> removes all of the path up to and including the last path separator (if any).

```
basename("abcd.com/efgh/ijkl/mnop")
# [1] "mnop"
```

It is vectorized, so you can just stick the whole column in there.

```
basename(rep("abcd.com/efgh/ijkl/mnop", 3))
# [1] "mnop" "mnop" "mnop"
```

So, to apply this to one column `link` of a data frame `webdata`, you can simply do

```
webdata$link <- basename(webdata$link)
```

The other obvious function would be `sub()`, but I think `basename()` will do the trick and it's easier.

```
sub(".*/", "", rep("abcd.com/efgh/ijkl/mnop", 3))
```

Comment: My data frame name is webdata. Also the "/" is dynamic. So it will not always be "mnop". It was be like "abcd.com/efgh/ijkl/aaaaaaaa" or "abcd.com/efgh/ijkl/xxyy-rr-rr-rr". Also I would like the resultant to be a data frame.

Comment: K, so do `data$column <- basename(data$column)`

Comment: @KshitijMarwah - did you even try `basename` on those examples? It works fine. `txt <- c("abcd.com/efgh/ijkl/aaaaaaaa", "abcd.com/efgh/ijkl/xxyy-rr-rr-rr"); basename(txt)` returns `[1] "aaaaaaaa"      "xxyy-rr-rr-rr"`

Comment: It throws the following error 
Error in basename(webdatatest$Page) : 
  a character vector argument expected

Comment: @KshitijMarwah - You probably have a factor.  Use `basename(as.character(webdatatest$Page))`

Comment: Let me guess: `is.character(webdatatest$Page)` is `FALSE` - you have a `factor` - convert it first - `webdatatest$Page <- as.character(webdatatest$Page)`

Comment: @thelatemail - Those are just examples. So the way my data is stored is in column form and those were some examples of data in my data frame column. Can you suggest some where my data frame name **webdatatest** which has column **page** on which I want to perfrom the operations.

Comment: Why do I feel like you're not even reading these comments and running the code?

Comment: @thelatemail - Got the result I needed. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @RichardScriven - I was a bit careless while executing code. Finally got the result.

Comment: @RichardScriven - I am facing another issue. When I run the code on other data set with over a million rows it gives me this error           Error in basename(webdata$Page) : path too long

Comment: @KshitijMarwah - Then I think you will want to use the `sub()` code instead, at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @RichardScriven  -I have used `sub(".*/", "", rep(webdata$Page, 3))` and it gave me first row . Now trying `d = webdata[sub(".*/", "", rep(webdata$Page, 3)),]`. Hoping this is correct and would work.

Comment: @KshitijMarwah - Do `webdatatest$Page <- sub(".*/", "", as.character(webdatatest$Page))`