# how to extract everything after \ in a string R

Tags: r, substring, backslash

So far I've tried...

```
sub("\.*", "", Array_of_Strings)
sub(".*[\]", "", Array_of_Strings)
```

I know that:

```
sub("\\\\.*", "", Array_of_Strings)
```

removes every thing before the backslash.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract text after "/" in a data frame in R Programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35146157/extract-text-after-in-a-data-frame-in-r-programming)

Comment: I need to know how to extract text after the backslash, not the forward slash. R treats backslashes very strangely.

Comment: Something like this? `gsub("(^.*\\\\)(.*$)", "\\2", "c:\\path.to.file")
`